# On drupal main page menu, number after /node/7/1

Tags: nodes, 7, blocks

i am starting to learn drupal right now. I downloaded a template and I am trying to figure out where are all the components are stored.

I encountered a problem where on the menu for website,  there are different submenu items under that menu. and one of the items has URL like this: www.example.com/node/7/1, another item URL like this: www.example.com/node/7/2, the list goes on, like www.example.com/node/7/3. When I click on any of those link, it brings me to the same page, however the representation is different.

I am able to find node 7 in the content, however i am not able to find how to configure the number after /node/7. Can somebody tell me what does that number means? Thank you very much and have a great day.

Comment: @No Sssweat the content is the same, only style is different, so it's not bring me back to the same page, it's actually a different page, but similar layout.

Comment: the true URL is [link](http://dev-testingcommerce.pantheon.io/node/7/1) and [link](http://dev-testingcommerce.pantheon.io/node/7/2)   or [link](http://dev-testingcommerce.pantheon.io/7)

Comment: this is definitely a preprocess or something in a tpl file. It looks to be related to related to the parallax banner. You might get a better explanation by contacting the theme developer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand the question, but my 2 cents.

First, default Drupal URLs take the format of `/{entity}/{id}/{action}`, eg. `/node/7/edit` and `/node/7/view`. In both cases you are looking at the `7`th `node` to be created, the first is the `edit` (admin) display, the second is the default display that visitors will see (`view` is dropped so you only see `/node/7`.

The second argument in your example is a little tricky as numbers don't give much away, so without knowing every module you have installed I would assume this is related to your template.

You can tell if this is the case by changing template to the default.

If these are the result of the custom template, the have a look in `template.php` as this is where theme level custom logic is done. On the off chance it hasn't been done well, have a look in the `page.tpl.php` and `node.tpl.php` files too.

Answer (score 0):

> When I click on any of those link, it brings me to the same page

That is Drupal's default behaviour. If it can't find a page, it displays you the parent.

Example, try going to: `/node/7/asdfkl` and it will show you `/node/7` since it can't find `asdfkl` which doesn't exist.

Not sure why your submenu links are like that... did you install a module that added those links?